# Passenger partially failing to serve site

Tags: postgresql, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

A rails3 application with Passenger4.0.53/nginx (installed via passenger) and postgresql 9.3.5 database is running... partially!

Calling the home URL is rendering the page as per the rails application controller=> home, action => index.

but hitting the login link, the proper URL is being generated, but the result is a 404 error.  Restarting passenger, then ngingx has failed to change behaviour...

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default is set as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name ranz2.iwant2go2.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env   development;
        root         /home/deploy/ranz/current/public;

       # location / {
       #         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       #         passenger_enabled on;
       #  }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root html;
        }
}
```

nginx error log

```
    [ 2014-10-14 07:42:57.7851 24433/7f42e3109780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'web_server_pid' => '24432', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2014-10-14 07:42:57.8090 24436/7f55db281780 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.24432/generation-0/request
[ 2014-10-14 07:42:57.8705 24441/7fbfd457b7c0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.24432/generation-0/logging
[ 2014-10-14 07:42:57.8715 24433/7f42e3109780 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2014-10-14 07:42:57.8865 24441/7fbfd457b7c0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:289 ]: Caught signal, exiting...
```

**Update**  seeing other similar questions, I disabled the 'passenger_enabled on;' instruction within the first location block. Restarted nginx and the application.  No change in behaviour. Subsequently I disable the first location block... Restarted nginx and the application. No change in behaviour.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in nginx.conf.  My understanding was that passenger_ruby should point to the result of `which ruby`, which is what I toggled to:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
# passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby;
```

However, **RTFM**, that returns a passenger error.  Whose contents point one in the proper direction *(good on 'ya Phusion!)*.  The manual, section "8.3.1. passenger_ruby " is explicit.

```
which passenger-config
```

paste that result in the subsequent commands

```
rvm use <desired_version>
<result_of_which passenger_config> --ruby-command
```

then from the output string you have the string to define passenger_ruby in nginx.conf, which should ressemble something like

```
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/wrappers/ruby
```